How to check window.ethereum is Okx Wallet?
I use wagmi (1.4.7) to connect MetaMask and Wallet Connect.
If I trigger connect function when Chrome browser had installed OKX Wallet and MetaMask Wallet, It will open OKX Wallet window not MetaMask.
I found someone had the same issue https://github.com/wevm/wagmi/discussions/2676, but the answer is not working. Because window.okxwallet is undefined
Also It's not working when I try to use detectOkxWallet function and window?.ethereum.isMetaMask.
const detectOkxWallet = async () => {
        const provider = window.ethereum;

        try {
            const accounts = await provider.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });

            console.log('detectOkxWallet accounts', accounts); // []
            console.log('detectOkxWallet provider.constructor?.name', provider.constructor?.name); // Nw
            if (accounts && provider.constructor?.name === 'OkxWalletProvider') {
                console.log('OKX Wallet detected via behavior');
                return true;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error detecting OKX Wallet:', error);
        }
        return false;
    }; 

Here is my connect setting:
_app.tsx:
import { WagmiConfig, configureChains, createConfig } from 'wagmi';
import { arbitrum, mainnet, arbitrumGoerli, arbitrumSepolia } from 'wagmi/chains';
import { MetaMaskConnector } from 'wagmi/connectors/metaMask';
import { WalletConnectConnector } from 'wagmi/connectors/walletConnect';

const chainsArray =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? [arbitrumSepolia, arbitrum, mainnet]
        : [arbitrumSepolia, arbitrum, mainnet];

const { chains, publicClient, webSocketPublicClient } = configureChains(
    chainsArray,
    [publicProvider()]
);


const config = createConfig({
    autoConnect: false,
    connectors: [
        new MetaMaskConnector({ chains }),
        new WalletConnectConnector({
            chains,
            options: {
                projectId: process.env.WALLET_CONNECT_PROJECT_ID,
                showQrModal: true,
            },
        }),
    ],
    publicClient,
    webSocketPublicClient,
});

How do I trigger connect
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useConnect, useDisconnect, useAccount, useSwitchNetwork, useNetwork } from 'wagmi';

const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');

    const { connect, connectors, error, isLoading, pendingConnector } = useConnect({
        async onSuccess(data, variables, context) {
            const { account, chain } = data;
            // call my API
            await signInWithEthereum(
                account,
                chain.id,
                pendingConnector?.id as string,
                referral as string
            );
        },
        onError(error, variables, context) {
            if (variables.connector.id === 'metaMask') {
                setErrorMsg(error.message);
            }
        },
    });

return (
  {connectors.map((connector, index) => (
    <View key={index}>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log('window ethereum isMetaMask', window?.ethereum.isMetaMask); // true
          console.log('window ethereum isOkxWallet', window?.ethereum.isOkxWallet); // undefined
          connect({ connector }); // open OKX Wallet not MetaMask Wallet
        })
      >
        {connector.name}
      </Button>
    </View>
  )}
);

